# Programmatically access ASP.NET MVC OutputCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, outputcache

I know it's called 'Output' cache, but is it possible at all to programmatically add/get/remove objects to the ASP.NET MVC OutputCache?
I do not want to cache Controller output, but only specific objects, which would be used by this and other controller actions later.

The reason I'm asking is because this would play well with distributed caching scenarios, rather than caches created using System.Runtime.Caching.